# "dataframe to google spreadsheet" TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets-api

Trying to insert a dataframe to google spreadsheet without using gspread_pandas or df2gspread libraries.
Because while using those libraries user have to put the credentials json file to %appdata.
Let's say I have five dataframe in a instance and I want to push those dataframe to five different spreadsheet. Can't do that with those libraries so here's the code i tried, and this error shows given below.

```
import pandas as pd
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import numpy as np
import gspread
from googleapiclient import discovery

data = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'])
print(df)

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('cred.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
sheet = client.open('SpreadsheetName').sheet1

sheets_service = discovery.build('sheets','v4',credentials=credentials)
sheets = sheets_service.spreadsheets()
spreadsheet_id = '************************'


def df_to_sheet(df):
    df_columns = [np.array(df.columns)]
    df_values = df.values.tolist()
    df_to_sheet = np.concatenate((df_columns, df_values)).tolist()
    return df_to_sheet

data = [
    {
        "title": "Unique URL",
        "df": pd.DataFrame({})
    }
]
update_body = {
        "valueInputOption": "RAW",
        "data": list(map(lambda d: {"range": d.get("title"), "values": df_to_sheet(d.get(df))}, data))
    }
sheets.values().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body=update_body).execute()
```

Error:

```
     Name  Age
0    Alex   10
1     Bob   12
2  Clarke   13
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Development/Selenium/slackdata/OLD Database/unique_url_finder_test.py", line 37, in <module>
    "data": list(map(lambda d: {"range": d.get("title"), "values": df_to_sheet(d.get(df))}, data))
  File "E:/Development/Selenium/slackdata/OLD Database/unique_url_finder_test.py", line 37, in <lambda>
    "data": list(map(lambda d: {"range": d.get("title"), "values": df_to_sheet(d.get(df))}, data))
  File "E:\Development\Selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1665, in __hash__
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Hi there @MDFARHAN! I have some doubts about your question. When you say «*Trying to insert a dataframe to google spreadsheet without using gspread_pandas or df2gspread libraries*», could you please clarify why you need to do that? I want to delineate the reason behind that operation in order to find a simpler way of doing it with the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api).

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron It is for a management software.